# How can I check if BMI2 instructions are available in my ifunc resolver?

Tags: gcc, intrinsics, bmi

I want to use the `_bzhi_u32` intrinsic, but I want to revert to a regular C implementation if the processor where the executable runs doesn't support the `BMI2` instruction set.

I'm using GCC 4.8.3 and I have the following

```
static inline uint32_t myfunc_bmi(uint32_t in) {
     return _bzhi_u32(in, 3); /* as an example */ 
}
static void * resolve_myfunc(void) {
  __builtin_cpu_init();.
  if (__builtin_cpu_is("corei7") return myfunc_bmi2;
  return myfunc_default;
}
static inline uint32_t myfunc(uint32_t in) __attribute__ ((ifunc "resolve_myfunc")));
```

I originally wanted to use `__builtin_cpu_support()` to check explicitly for `BMI2` but seems that you can't check for that with `__builtin_cpu_support()`. My current check of `corei7` doesn't seem perfect either because as I understand some mobile versions of i7 Haswell doesn't have `BMI2` (I tried on a VirtualBox Linux guest running on Windows 7 on i7-3520@2.9GHZ and it raises a `SIGILL Illegal Instruction`).

So is there a fail-safe way to check for `BMI2`?

Comment: The above `__builtin_cpu_is("corei7")` actually returns `false` on the VirtualBox Linux Guest.

Comment: [You can answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214843/compiler-macro-to-detect-bmi2-instruction-set) rather than leave this question unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **__builtin_cpu_supports** is working for me (GCC 5.1).. GCC 4.9 and lower versions does not support BMI2 detection.

Try this ->

```
__builtin_cpu_init ();
if (__builtin_cpu_supports("bmi2")) {
    printf("BMI2 supported \n");
}
```

To resolve your issue you should update your GCC version.

Alternatively use **CPUID** and extract the BMI2 bit if you don't want to update your GCC.

/A